# Is there a way to remove users from the Google SignIn Page?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

the app I am developing is meant for businesses that have few iPad devices and many clients.
The clients will use these iPads to sign in. That means multiple clients will use and share one device. I offer sign-in using email or sign-in using Google.

However when the client signs into the app and then logs out (calling

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect()
```

the credentials remain in the Google Sign In form upon next log-in process and the process doesn't even require a password. See image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLDfi.jpg

Is there any way to prevent this? I don't want other clients to see other clients' emails. I understand this kind of login is made for personal devices but I was wondering if this problem could be solved for a shared device. I dug through a lot of documentation and didn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you revoked access [1] to your app for the user that logged out, later users won't be able to sign-in to their account.

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#tokenrevoke

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however this doesn't solve the issue that the user's account/email stays in the log in window after logging out. The only way to remove it from there is to clear Safari cookies from the Settings app. Which is bad.

Comment: If you're creating an app for shared devices isn't that the right thing to do to avoid leaking data across users?

Comment: Yes it is. But it is a bad user experience. We can't expect them to do this every logout. So we decided to remove Google login.